getting error when modifying the javascript property using Object.defineProperty()


obj = [{
    prop11: 'value1',
    prop21: 'value2'
  },
  {
    prop12: 'value1',
    prop22: 'value2'
  },
  {
    key3: {}
  }
];

obj.forEach(element => {
  Object.defineProperty(obj.key3, 'prop1', {
    value: "xx",
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  })
});
console.log(obj.prop1)



getting error - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a non-null object
tried several ways of this and also Object.defineProperties() but couldn't get working.

Only one of the elements in your array has a "key3" property, so the attempt will fail on the other elements.

Also your .forEach() callback is incorrect anyway, because you reference obj instead of element.

There's absolutely no reason to use Object.defineProperty here, and the error has nothing to do with it either. Same as obj.key3.prop1 = "xx". To fix it, use (element.key3 ??= {}).prop1 = "xx";

sorry, if I use this expression error is gone but, outcome is undefined with above console statement. Also would like to know why should we not use defineProperty() as I'm trying to modify property value here.

console.log(obj.key3.prop1) gives me  TypeError: obj.key3 is undefined

@VijayGRama obj is, despite the name, an array of objects. It doesn't have a key3 property indeed.

You need to correctly access key3 in your obj array and then define the property on it, To do so you need to find the object within the array that contains the key3 property after that create/define the property you need in the key3 object.
Refer the code below for reference:


let obj = [{
    prop11: 'value1',
    prop21: 'value2'
  },
  {
    prop12: 'value1',
    prop22: 'value2'
  },
  {
    key3: {}
  }
];


const key3Object = obj.find(element => element.key3); // get the object containing key3

if (key3Object && key3Object.key3) {
  Object.defineProperty(key3Object.key3, 'newProperty', {
    value: "newPropertyValueHere",
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(key3Object.key3.newProperty));  




Thanks, this piece of code is working fine but somehow, when I applied to my program, it is showing same error.
